# insert data issue. inside php loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a HTML form which have only "value" text field.But user can generate any number of "value" test field for 1 submit button. Here is my table

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insert` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `insert_operation` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `value` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now if user generates 4 "value" text field and enter 4 **value** data like(a,b,c,d) it should perform 4 insert query but **insert_operation** track  of every submit button  click.

It'll look like below

```
 Id Insert_operation value
  1   1                 a
  2   1                 b
  3   1                 c
  4   1                 d
  5   2                 x
  6   2                 a
```

my html form has value text field which name is value and submit button which name is save.

I am not sure of my php code.
I know the Insert query must be inside PHP loop. But how can I perform?

Comment: where is your html or php?

Comment: I need your form code and insert query code that you are currently using.

Comment: INSERT INTO 'insert' VAULES('',$i,$value); without loop

Comment: can you please update your question with proper html and php code so that I can correct the same.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala the problem is I am unable to write html tag in question box.  I have 1 text input name is "value". But it can 1 more. user generate any number of "value" text field

Comment: are $i(which is =1 before while loop) and $I (which is incremented in while loop) same in your code? Because PHP variables are case sensitive. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: I want to know how does user increment text fields. Post that part of code.

Comment: suppose by using jquery user can add text field

Comment: `while($_POST['value']=1){`. That's an infinite loop right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your `value` fields are all named the same ie. `<input name="value[]" ... />`

Try something like this -

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['value']);$i++){
   $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value'][$i]);
   if($i == 0){  // if the first increase MAX(insert_operation) by 1
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO `insert` SELECT null, IFNULL((SELECT MAX(insert_operation)+1 from `insert`), 1), '{$value}'");
   }
   else {   // if not the first use MAX(insert_operation)
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `insert` SELECT null, IFNULL((SELECT MAX(insert_operation) from `insert`), 1), '{$value}'");
   }
}
```

The first one will get the `MAX(insert_operation)` that is already in the table, and if null will set it to 1, else it will increase by 1. All the rest will just set `insert_operation` to `MAX(insert_operation)`.

See this SqlFiddle Example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afdc0/1

---

a few notes. `insert` is a mysql [function/reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). It would be better to rename your table, but at the very least it needs to be in backticks - `. You should be escaping any user data (`$_POST['value']`), in this case I showed [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Finally, `mysql_*` functions are depreciated as of php5.5. You should update to `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: awesome @Sean. I  was really trouble for this. you solve this easily. I use CODEIGNITER. SO I am not use mysql_* functions. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
mysql_query(INSERT INTO 'insert' VALUES('','$i','$_POST['value']'));
```

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) expects the first parameter to be a SQL string, so the correct parameter would be:

```
mysql_connect("
    INSERT INTO 
        `insert` (`insert_operation`, `value`) 
    VALUES 
        ($i, '{$_POST['value']}')
");
```

It's good to add the columns as well, because the your table may change after so time, and if this happens, your SQL won't work.

Other error is that you are using assignment instead of comparison
`while($_POST['value']=1)` assigns the value.
You have to use `==` to check if the value is equal to 1 like so `while($_POST['value'] == 1)`

PS It's not a good idea to use MySQL functions as table names and it's not a good idea to use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated as of php 5.5 and will be removed

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
<?php
for ($i=1;$i<=$no_of_text_field;$i++) // no of text fields user can add
{
?>
<input type="text" name="value<?php echo $i ?>">
<?php
}
?>
<input type="text" name="no_of_text_field<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $no_of_text_field ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    for ($k=1;$k<=$_REQUEST['no_of_text_field'];$k++)  //getting values of all text fields
    {
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO `insert` VALUES('','$i','$_REQUEST[value].$k')");
    }
}
?>
```

Check the above code this should give you some idea